# How to set the values of a column as columns in dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm looking for a better code to transform my `DataFrame`.
My `DataFrame` looks like this:

```
    Period  LASTDATE    PRICE   VAT SUM CLIENT
0   2018Q1  31/3/2018   1       2   3   NAME
1   2018Q2  30/6/2018   2       2   4   NAME
2   2018Q3  30/9/2018   3       3   6   NAME
3   2018Q4  31/12/2018  4       4   8   NAME
```

I want to achieve this:

```
    2018Q1  2018Q2  2018Q3  2018Q4  LASTDATE    SUM
NAME    3     4       6        8    31/12/2018  21
```

So far I split the `Period` column from the `DataFrame` and make it a header. I believe there's a better way to code this. I searched the documentation of pandas and I believe, `set_index()` might help me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create `Series` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for index by `Period`, convert to one column `DataFrame` by [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html), transpose by [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) and last add new columns by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df1 = (df.set_index('Period')['SUM']
         .to_frame()
         .T
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
         .assign(LASTDATE = df['LASTDATE'].iat[-1], SUM = df['SUM'].sum()))
print (df1)
     2018Q1  2018Q2  2018Q3  2018Q4    LASTDATE  SUM
SUM       3       4       6       8  31/12/2018   21
```

Comment: I would Like to have name as index

Comment: @Magotte - Sorry, change `.to_frame()` to `.to_frame('NAME')`

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, jezrael's answer won't work if you have more than 1 client and it doesn't give you the client name as the index (as in your example output).
Try the following:

```
df1 = df.pivot(index='CLIENT', columns='Period', values='SUM')
df_agg = df.groupby('CLIENT').agg({'LASTDATE': 'last', 'SUM': 'sum'})
df_fin = pd.concat([df1, df_agg], axis=1)
```

In the first line, you reshape the data frame, but lose the LASTDATE value, which you bring back in with the second line (together with the total sum for each client) and then combine the data frames in the last line.
For an expanded imaginary data frame:

```
   Period    LASTDATE  PRICE  VAT  SUM CLIENT
0  2018Q1   31/3/2018      1    2    3  NAME1
1  2018Q2   30/6/2018      2    2    4  NAME1
2  2018Q3   30/9/2018      3    3    6  NAME1
3  2018Q4  31/12/2018      4    4    8  NAME1
4  2018Q1   31/3/2018      2    2    1  NAME2
5  2018Q2   30/6/2018      4    2    2  NAME2
6  2018Q3   30/9/2018      6    3    3  NAME2
7  2018Q4  31/12/2018      8    4    4  NAME2
```

you should get the following:

```
        2018Q1  2018Q2  2018Q3  2018Q4    LASTDATE  SUM
CLIENT                                                 
NAME1        3       4       6       8  31/12/2018   21
NAME2        1       2       3       4  31/12/2018   10
```

Tested on pandas 0.24.1.

Comment: I was parsing client one by one, so it worked fine. I will try to alter my code and try your solution as well.

Comment: A very nice approach and is working! I modified my program to work based on your solution and I got to admit it's really fast. Although to be fair I asked a specific question with one client at a time and the jezrael's answer was correct in that specific case. Thanks for your effort, you got my respect.

Comment: No worries :D I just wanted to provide a more general answer as I had a feeling you (or someone else) might head down that road soon enough.